# Create New Variable from Column Index Value

Tags: r

My goal is to create a new variable that contains the value indicated by a column index.

```
c <- rep(1:2)
d <- rep(1:10)
e <- c(1,5,7,2,3,9,1,6,9,1)
z <- cbind(d,e,c)
```

I would like to create a new variable (f) that is the value indicated by the column index of c.

```
d   e   c   f
1   1   1   1
2   5   2   5
3   7   1   3
4   2   2   2
5   3   1   5
6   9   2   9
7   1   1   7
8   6   2   6
9   9   1   9
10  1   2   1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use row/column indexing to extract the elements from the first 2 columns of 'z', where the row index is the sequence of rows and column index is 'c' column from the `matrix` 'z'

```
cbind(z, f = z[,1:2][cbind(seq_len(nrow(z)), z[,"c"])])
#       d e c f
# [1,]  1 1 1 1
# [2,]  2 5 2 5
# [3,]  3 7 1 3
# [4,]  4 2 2 2
# [5,]  5 3 1 5
# [6,]  6 9 2 9
# [7,]  7 1 1 7
# [8,]  8 6 2 6
# [9,]  9 9 1 9
#[10,] 10 1 2 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am receiving the following error message when I try this: `Unsupported index type: data.frame`

Comment: @user647764  Not sure about your error.  It works for me based on the example provided

Comment: the issue was that my data was in a tibble format; coercing it to data frame fixed the issue and this worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An option could be use `mapply` to get desired output.

```
cbind(z, f = mapply(function(x,y)z[y,x], z[,"c"], 1:nrow(z)))
#    d e c f
# d  1 1 1 1
# e  2 5 2 5
# d  3 7 1 3
# e  4 2 2 2
# d  5 3 1 5
# e  6 9 2 9
# d  7 1 1 7
# e  8 6 2 6
# d  9 9 1 9
# e 10 1 2 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! When I attempt to use mapply it returns a list with all the values in the other columns, is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @user647764 The result I have shown is after using `mapply` on dataframe provided by you. Are you getting list when you used it on real dataframe? Can you please share part of out your are getting?